# SQL Syntax Error when using date_trunc

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a view for a table using SQL. Unfortunately my coworker is suddenly out for an extended period of time and he's the only one who fully understood this stuff.

I am trying to create a view that will get the last 90 days of data (not quite all the way there yet) but mainly I'm just trying to get it to run for now, I can debug and get specifics to work once it actually runs.

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE VIEW v_month_table_name AS 
SELECT
(date_trunc('DAY'::text, 
   (
      table_name.date
   )
   ::timestamp with time zone))::date AS day,
   table_name.finance_id_desc,
   table_name.spid,
   table_name.sp_name,
   sum(table_name.total_payments) AS total_payments,
   sum(table_name.total_payments_amount) AS total_payments_amount,
FROM
   table_name 
GROUP BY
   date_trunc('DAY'::text, 
   (
      table_name.date
   )
   ::timestamp with time zone),
   table_name.finance_id_desc,
   table_name.spid,
   table_name.sp_name;
```

So when I run this code in SQL Developer I only get

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
  Position: 504
```

But when I plug it into an online syntax checker I get

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
   '::text, 
   (
      table_name.date
   )
   ::timestamp with time zone))::dat' at line 4
```

I have looked at some of the other SQL in our code base for stuff very similar to this and it seems like everything is the same where it can be.

I have a feeling that my problem is a simple one with a simple solution and I'm just glancing right over it.

Comment: please alter your tags, this is not M$ SQL server syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma off your last column:

```
sum(table_name.total_payments_amount) AS total_payments_amount
```

That's the cause of most 'syntax error at or near "FROM"' messages.